# Getting ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I started a new project with Eclipse Luna with MobileFirst Studio v.7.0.0-20150312-0731. The project has nothing else than a simple home page with a button and login input. After building the project for Android, when I run the application on the Android AVD emulator (both 4.4.2 API 19 and 5.0.1 API 21) I get:

> Application Error net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>   (file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)

[image: Android Emulator image]

Comment: When you say "simple", what do you mean by that? Can you provide your MFP project so others could experience this error?

Comment: When I say "simple" I mean it's the default project with default options. I just modified 
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

Comment: When you mention things like "login form", do you mean just the bare-bones HTML or anything else in it, like actual authentication code? that's what I mean. The question description does not help in understanding that thus an example project that can be run locally and debugged is the better course of action.

Comment: Pure html, just to show something on the screen:
<body style="display: none;">
      <!--application UI goes here-->
      <h2>Hello MobileFirst</h2>
      <hr>
      <form>
       <div><input type="text" placeholder="username"></div>
       <div><input type="password" placeholder="password"></div>
       <br>
       <button type="button">Login</button>
      </form>

Comment: The project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4CaNcOAiojnY3BPTEEyOGl1MXM&authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse Java EE Luna 4.4.2 with MFP Studio 7.0.0.00-20150402-2001 (can be downloaded from the Eclipse Marketplace) I've created and new project with a Hybrid application containing the Android environment.

In this application I have edited its index.html to contain your HTML from the comment - note that this then is completely not required as it changes nothing in regards to the issue you're experiencing.

The below was performed also with the provided sample, which was imported into the Eclipse workspace.

I've proceeded to right-click on the Android folder > Run As > Android Studio project (I have Android Studio installed and set-up via Eclipse preferences > MobileFirst). In Android Studio I have an AVD setup with API Level 19 (Android 4.4.2). Clicking the play button launches the Android Emulator and the end result is:

[image]

Comment: Ok, just curious: and if you launch the application without calling Android Studio, with Run As > Android Application, do you have the same result?

Comment: Works with ADT as well. Sounds like a development environment issue to me. Make sure you've installed the Android Emulator hardware acceleration option from the Android SDK Manager (require post-download installation).

Comment: I did. Android SDK and AVD updated. HAXM installed and working. It turns out that (with both versions 201503 and 201504) the Android Project generated by Eclipse is missing something, so the only way to make it working is to use Android Studio. I'd like to know if I'm the only one to have such a problem. I have a rather standard dev env (on Win8.1)

Comment: Missing what? It's a generated template... try to find the different. Since it's working for me in both, I'm doubtful...